# Search across multiple lines and copy them to clipboard

Tags: search, vim, copy

I have multiple python scripts in my menu.vim file.
I want to copy them to clipboard.

All python scripts are like this one:

```
python3 << endpython   
.......code......   
endpython
```

I use this search command:

```
^python3\_.\{-}\_^endpython
```

It seems to me that it is the correct command even if does not highlight all lines (maybe because the scripts are longer than my screen display).

But how do I copy a multiple lines search to the clipboard?
Is this the way to go?

```
g/pattern/y A
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right; the solution involves `:global` (to iterate over all matched ranges), and an uppercase register (to accumulate the ranges):

```
:let @a = '' | global/^python3/,/^endpython/yank A
```

If you need the result in the system clipboard, you can do this via

```
:let @+ = @a
```

#### Plugin alternative

If these multiple commands are too much of a hassle, my [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) provides (among others) this shortcut command:

```
:YankRanges/^python3/,/^endpython/ +
```

Comment: Thank you. Why did you change the search from `\_.\{-}\_^` to `/,/^`? Was my search command not correct?

Comment: Yours was a single multi-line pattern, mine is two patterns, one for the start of the range (fed to `:global`, the other to the end of the range, passed (together with the current line set by `:global`) to the `:yank` command.

Comment: More verbose version: `:global/^python3/    .,/^endpython/yank`

Comment: I've never seen this `/ .,/` and still don't understand it very well (I'm just a hobbyist programmer) but thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
:g/^python3/,/^endpython/y +
```

I think the "missing part" here is that you can use the special `+` and `*` registers to interact with the clipboard. See [`:help quoteplus`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui_x11.txt.html#quoteplus) and [`:help quotestar`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui.txt.html#quotestar).

Also see [How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/84/51) for a more in-depth explanation of Vim and clipboard interaction.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You gave the same answer as Ingo but I noted that it only copies one python script, not all scripts (no append).

Comment: @Reman Ah, I didn't realise you wanted to copy it all at the same time. Only way to do that is the intermediate register as in Ingo's answer.